# Find and prove the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}}{2^n+3^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find and prove the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}}{2^n+3^n}$$
which according to WolframAlpha happens to be $27$.

The furthest I could get is
$$\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}}{2^n+3^n} = 4\left(1 + \frac{3^{n}}{2^n+3^n}\right)$$

Comment: Should be the limit as $n \to +\infty$?

Comment: @tilper Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Divide numerator and denominator by $3^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}}{2^n+3^n}=\frac{(4)2^{n}+(27)3^{n}}{2^n+3^n}=\frac{(4)2^{n}/3^n+(27)1}{2^n/3^n+1}$$
so the limit is $27$

Answer (score 0):

$$2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}\sim_\infty 3^{n+3}, \qquad 2^n+3^n\sim_\infty 3^n,$$
hence
$$\frac{2^{n+2}+3^{n+3}}{2^n+3^n}\sim_\infty\frac{3^{n+3}}{3^n}=3^3.$$